# Audio cannot be decoded (Firefox only)

Tags: firefox, audio, mp3

When trying to play certain audio files loaded from a blob in Firefox, I get this error:

```
Media resource xyz.mp3 could not be decoded, error: Error Code: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_DECODE_ERR (0x806e0004)
Details: virtual mozilla::MediaResult mozilla::FFmpegAudioDecoder<46465650>::DoDecode(mozilla::MediaRawData *, uint8_t *, int, bool *, mozilla::MediaDataDecoder::DecodedData &): FFmpeg audio error:-1094995529
```

Any ideas why this is happening? I don't get the error on Chrome, and it's unclear why this is happening for some audio files and not others. If you load the original mp3 directly in firefox, it plays fine (i.e. click "xyz.mp3" in the error message).

The FFmpeg error is: AVERROR_INVALIDDATA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ffmpeg exit status -1094995529](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780931/ffmpeg-exit-status-1094995529)

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure how to figure out what's causing the data to be invalid